# Python cv2 sending frame over to React client

Tags: python, reactjs, opencv, computer-vision

How can react read cv2 frame created in python? I am sending over frames from my backend:

```
def send_frame(response):
    print(response)
    socketio.emit('response', response)

@app.route('/analytics/detection', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def show_detections():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fp = request.json['filepath']
        for resp in obj.tracking(fp):
            send_frame(resp)

def tracking(file):
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
    current_frame = 0
    while True:
        sucess, frame = capture.read()
        if(sucess):
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frame_name = 'frame.jpg'
        cv2.imwrite(frame_name, frame) 
        frame = open(frame_name,'rb').read()
            .
            .
        yield frame
```

How do I read and display this frame in React?

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 relatively easy methods that you can use:

1. **Static files** - easy but inefficient:
   Store the jpg file somewhere inside the web root folder and notify the client using websockets about the new frames, on the client side just bind it to an image element.
2. [**Send the image inside a websocket message**](https://medium.com/tsftech/using-web-sockets-to-update-images-8c66327f39a3)
3. **Stream the image using as MJPEG stream** - probably the most efficient method out of the 3 and doesn't require any client code for frame updates:
   here is a good code [reference code](https://gist.github.com/walchko/0deed4152896e1940b0fe93c9eb4d061) for a python MJPEG server that you can embed in you application